# Singing, is it haram in this case?

Tags: singing

I have a question. Can you sing an english song from the internet without bad words and without anyone in the room with no instruments? I need a very straight forward answer, my sect. is Salafi. I read you can't sing because it takes you out of reality and the remembrance of Allah, but I want to sing to help me feel better and if it's about the remembrance, wouldn't studying be bad? Since you don't necessarily remember Allah 24/7 unless you want to pray. But is it bad if there is no bad words, no audience, or no instruments?

Answer (score -2):

The straightforward answer is it is not Haram because there is no evidence to support it. God did not declare it Haram in the Quran and there is no mutawatir Hadith to support it.

Comment: Ibn Abbas interpreted 31:6 as referring to singing